# jquery: Find and loop through all spans with certain ID within a div?

Tags: jquery, replace

I have a list that is numbered for each item (1,2,3,4..). I have a function that removes items but when it removes an item the list numbers are not in order anymore (1,3,4...).

What I am trying to do is find all spans starting with "id_" and get the full ID so can can reset the numbers to the correct order.

```
$('[id^="table_"]').each(function(index, table){

});
```

The way I am trying to do it I cannot figure out how to get the ID of the span.

```
<div id="list">

  <div id="list_1">
    <table border="0" width="100%" id="table_1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span id="id_1">1</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="list_2">
    <table border="0" width="100%" id="table_2">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span id="id_2">2</span>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks

**UPDATED**

Ok I have taken a bits from each post to get this

```
var i = 1;

$('span[id^="id_"]', "#list").each(function(index){

   var id = this.id;
   $('#'+id).html(i+'. ');

   i++;

});
```

Thanks all for you help.

Comment: alert($('span:first', this).attr('id')); what does this do.

Comment: @PENDO - This works fine. But for learning sake what id the span wasn't the first element how would I find by "id_". You might aswell post as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: done :) also added something concerning your question, however I'm not 100% sure that works.

Comment: .. so you actually wanted to change the text and not the id... *bad wording* ..

Answer (score 2):

**Update** I missed that you already had an `each` loop. It looks fine except you seem to be looking for `id`s starting with "table_", but you don't have any (you have "list_" and "id_"). Also, you're doing it completely unbounded, which will probably be quite a lot of work. The more narrow the selector can be, the better (usually).

> The way I am trying to do it I cannot figure out how to get the ID of the span.

Within an `each` loop, the `id` of the DOM element is available as `this.id`.

My original answer addresses how to do this with the markup you quoted.

---

**Original answer**:

jQuery has the ["attribute starts with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), so you can find all the children that are `span`s with an `id` starting with "id_" and then loop through assigning new IDs to them:

```
$("#list").find('span[id^="id_"]').each(function(index) {
    this.id = "id_" + (index + 1);
});
```

That uses [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find them, then [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through them. I assumed there you wanted to start the numbering with 1 rather than with 0, hence adding one to the `index` that jQuery passes into `each. Assigning the IDs can be done with the raw DOM element (`this`in the`each` callback) as there's nothing complicated about it.

Although actually, you don't need a separate call to `find`, you can just use a descendant selector:

```
$('#list span[id^="id_"]').each(function(index) {
    this.id = "id_" + (index + 1);
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uquli4)

---

**Further update**: If you really want to have fun, you can renumber the lists, the tables within the lists, and the spans within the tables:

```
$('#list div[id^="list_"]').each(function(listIndex) {
  // This is called for each list, we renumber them...
  ++listIndex; // So it's 1-based
  this.id = "list_" + listIndex;

  // ...then process the tables within them
  $(this).find('table[id^="table_"]').each(function(tblIndex) {
    // Called for each table in the list, we renumber them...
    ++tblIndex; // 1-based
    this.id = "table_" + listIndex + "_" + tblIndex;

    // ...then process the spans
    $(this).find('span[id^="id_"]').each(function(spanIndex) {
      // Called for each span in the table
      ++spanIndex; // 1-based
      this.id = "id_" + listIndex + "_" + tblIndex + "_" + spanIndex;
    });
  });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uquli4/2)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - index + 1 wont work, what if they has already been items removed already the index will not match "id_". This was my first try.

Comment: @Billy: The `index` that jQuery passes into `each` is the index of that element in the matched set. It doesn't relate to the `id` at all (until we use it to create an `id`). So it will always start with `0`, then the next call it will be `1`, etc. until all matched elements have been visited.

Comment: @T.J. don't know if the question has been edited but there are `table_` ids for the table elements..

Comment: @Billy: And I added a further example, mostly to show how you can approach things in various ways and to demonstrate `each` and nesting.

Comment: @T.J. the OP just wanted to change the text of the spans.. *as it seems from the inline answer to the question* ..

Answer (score 0):

If a framework-agnostic solution is acceptable, something along the following lines should do the trick:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("targetDivId");
var displayNum = 1;
var nodes = myDiv.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var index = 0; index < nodes.length; index++) {
    var node = nodes[index];
    if (node.id.indexOf("id_") == 0) {
        node.id = "id_" + displayNum;
        node.innerHTML = displayNum;
        displayNum++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [attributeStartsWith selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$('span[id^="id_"]', "#list").each(function(i){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$('[id^="table_"]').each(function(index, table){
  $('span:first', this).attr('id');
});
```

Basically this looks for the FIRST span element inside each table. If there would be more spans, you would have to combine both:

```
$('[id^="table_"]').each(function(index, table){
  $('span[id^="id_"]:first', this).attr('id');
});
```

Not 100% sure if the last one works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the ids of each groups *list, table and span* then you will need to

```
// for each list
$('[id^="list_"]').each(function(index, table){
  // for the inner table and span and the actual list
  $('table[id^="table_"], span[id^="id_"]', this).add(this).each(function(){
    // split the id to the prefix and number
    var id_parts = this.id.split('_');
    // assign new id based on existing prefix and the new number
    this.id = id_parts[0] + '_' + (index+1);
  })
});
```

if you want to change the text as well then use

```
// for each list
$('[id^="list_"]').each(function(index, table){
  // for the inner table and span and the actual list
  $('table[id^="table_"], span[id^="id_"]', this).add(this).each(function(){
    // split the id to the prefix and number
    var id_parts = this.id.split('_');
    // assign new id based on existing prefix and the new number
    this.id = id_parts[0] + '_' + (index+1);
    // single out the span and change its text
  }).filter('span').text(index+1);
});
```